# Possible to Obtain Active Bluetooth Connection Details? Protocol version? Profile? Codec?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, samsung-galaxy-s-8

Is it possible to obtain details about an active bluetooth connection in Android?

Protocol version is what I most want to know, such as if a bluetooth 5.0 peripheral is connecting to the device using bluetooth 5 and not 4. Also would be great to see the profile/codec being used as well.

I've looked and somewhat to my surprise I didn't find a way to do this either natively in android or using any third party apps.